# Insert label column into column content in data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with different columns and I need to insert the label of each column into the content of the column.

```
df['colour','season','food']

colour  season  food
white   winter  meat
yellow  summer  fruit
red     fall    soup
```

I need to do an operation like this `df.col1.add(' col1')` for each column, with the label ahead the content. My results has to be a new data frame df1 like

```
df1['colour','season','food']

colour         season         food
colour white   season winter  food meat
colour yellow  season summer  food fruit
colour red     season fall    food soup
```

I don't know how to iterate `df.col1.add(' col1')` for each columns and `.add()` set the label after the content instead before.

Any suggestion? please

Comment: `"colour " + df["colour"]`. To iterate, dfs loop over columns by default so it's just i.e. `for column in df:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No loop needed due to pandas intrinsic data alignment:

```
df.columns + ' ' + df
```

Output:

```
          colour         season        food
0   colour white  season winter   food meat
1  colour yellow  season summer  food fruit
2     colour red    season fall   food soup
```

Comment: Great! I took it!

Answer (score 1):

Try a for loop like this

```
for c in df.columns:
    df[c] = c + ' ' + df[c]
```

Comment: Thanks Federico. I tried it and It works but more elegant the solution on the top :).

Comment: I completely agree: it is super-elegant and efficient